# Solve won't solve

Tags: equation-solving

I try to solve a system of equations, there are 4 eqs and 4 variables I need to get. There are some other symbolic constants as well. When I try to solve, it shows empty backets: Out[n]={}. Is it unsolvable or have I made a mistake?

```
dpds = w*(1 + d/n)*(1 - chi)*nsu*
   k*(1 + c)/chi/(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n))*(1 + 
     60*a*chi*(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n))^2/
         S/(1 - chi)/(1 + c)*(2*s + sigma)) + w*(1 + d/n)*k*nsu*b
dpdd = w*
   tau/n*(s/60*(1 - chi)*nsu*
      k*(1 + c)/(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n)) + 
     chi*a*(s + sigma)) + w/n*(s + sigma)*k*nsu*b
dpdy = -w*(1 + d/n)*(s + sigma)*k^2*nsu*
  rho*(1 - y/n)/(b - q - gamma*n)^2
dpdw = (1 + d/n)*s*(1 - chi)*nsu*
   k*(1 + c)/60/
     chi/(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n)) + (1 + 
    d/n) + (s + sigma)*a*nsu*
   k*(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n)) + 
  2*(1 + d/n)*(s + sigma)*k*nsu*b
dpdq = -w*(1 + d/n)*(s + sigma)*rho*(1 - y/n)*nsu*k*
  a/(b - q - gamma*n)^2
Solve[dpds == dpdd && dpds == dpdw && dpds == dpdy && 
  dpds == dpdq, {s, d, y, q}]
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The posted code is incomplete, e.g. `dpds` is not defined. Please fix it.

Comment: What if any constraints exist on the variables and constants? Are any real, positive, negative, nonnegative, integer, ... Edit question with any additional info.

Comment: @Rohit-Namjoshi You're right, thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: @Bob-Hanlon Well, all the constants and variables should be real and positive, but I'm not sure how it can help to make this code work. I just need symbolic expressions for 4 variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
dpds = k*(1 + c)/
     chi/(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n))*(1 + 
     60*a*chi*(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n))^2/
         S/(1 - chi)/(1 + c)*(2*s + sigma)) + w*(1 + d/n)*k*nsu*b
dpdd = w*tau/
    n*(s/60*(1 - chi)*nsu*
      k*(1 + c)/(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n)) + 
     chi*a*(s + sigma)) + w/n*(s + sigma)*k*nsu*b
dpdy = -w*(1 + d/n)*(s + sigma)*k^2*nsu*
  rho*(1 - y/n)/(b - q - gamma*n)^2
dpdw = (1 + d/n)*s*(1 - chi)*nsu*
   k*(1 + c)/60/
     chi/(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n)) + (1 + 
    d/n) + (s + sigma)*a*nsu*
   k*(1 - rho*(b - q)/(b - q - gamma*n)*(1 - y/n)) + 
  2*(1 + d/n)*(s + sigma)*k*nsu*b
dpdq = -w*(1 + d/n)*(s + sigma)*rho*(1 - y/n)*nsu*k*
  a/(b - q - gamma*n)^2
```

I assume your first line is dpds..you should set your variables with `=` and not `:=` have a look at [this page for syntax infos](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

```
Solve[dpds == dpdd && dpds == dpdw && dpds == dpdy && dpds == dpdq, {s, d, y, q}]
```

It's unclear if Solve can solve this even, I gave up after 10 minutes....

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the code, adding the correct expression for dpds, and changed := to =. It didn't really help, because it still shows Out[n] = { } after a quick evaluation.

Comment: Copy and paste my code and try again...there is nothing quick about that evaluation.

Comment: You wrote dpds incorrectly, somehow the code was cut way after the := in my first post.

Comment: @Anastasia there is no solution for your variables with current restrictions.